# Translation: File upload error. Could not move uploaded file

Tags: debugging

I would like to import an translation file *.po. When I import it, I become the error:
"For security reasons, your upload has been renamed to bootstrap-all.de_.po." and "Error message File upload error. Could not move uploaded file."

Could anyone help?

Comment: Whatever UI you're using needs to be updated to allow `.po` as a valid extension - could you explain in detail how you're running the import?

Comment: I try to import the file in the Interface translation /admin/config/regional/translate/import. Then I choose the file "bootstrap-all.de.po"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to `admin/config/media/file-system` page
- Set **Temporary directory** field to `sites/default/files/temp`
- Save changes

**ALSO**

- Check that `sites/files` is writable.